# How to tar the muliple files with pattern match and remove same files which are being tar?

Tags: linux

```
> ls -lrt
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash     480074 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTAS.txt.160219054239
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash       1745 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATLR03_FTR_INPUT_ZD.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash     480074 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTCT.txt.160219033636
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash      11501 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTCB.txt.160219113017
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash       1745 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATLR03_FTR_INPUT_CG.txt
> tar cvf my_path.tar FP_ATL*
a FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTM6.txt.160219011039 29 blocks.
a FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTST.txt.160218130018 266 blocks.
a FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTZK.txt.151224122755 4 blocks.
a FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTZP.txt.160218102356 4 blocks.
a FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTZT.txt.160218191832 4 blocks.
> ls -lrt
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash     480074 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTAS.txt.160219054239
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash       1745 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATLR03_FTR_INPUT_ZD.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash     480074 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTCT.txt.160219033636
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash      11501 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATL_EXTCRP003FTR_INPUTCB.txt.160219113017
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash       1745 Feb 19 16:56 FP_ATLR03_FTR_INPUT_CG.txt
-rw-r--r--    1 akash akash    1413120 Feb 22 16:30 my_path.tar
```

I want to remove the files which are being compressed by tar command. How I can achieve this in single commmand line ?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Can you please edit and add a bit more detail?

Comment: how does zip -mj my.zip file_names works. Same working I want for tar command. Please help

Answer (score 0):

To closely replicate the behavior of `zip -mj` with `tar`, you can use this command:

```
tar --transform 's/.*\///' --remove-files -cvf my_path.tar FP_ATL*
```

Note that this doesn't compress the files that are added to the tarball. You will need to add one of the compression options like `-z` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kurt Stutsman..
This command has worked: tar --remove-files -czvf my_fiels.tar de_*